# Why does the generator send method print results to the screen without a call to the print function?

Tags: python, generator, yield

See the console session below:

```
>>> def f(x):
...  for _ in range(10):
...   y = yield
...   x.append(y)
...   yield x
...
>>> x = []
>>> g = f(x)
>>> for _ in g:
...  g.send(1)
...
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Note that the `.send()` method is causing the generator output to be printed to the screen. I believe it is the `.send()` method causing because if the generator output is `None`, then nothing is printed to the screen (which is the usual case with `None`).

```
>>> x = []
>>> g = f(x)
>>> for i in g:
...  g.send(1)
...
>>> x
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Additionally, if we just iterate through without sending any input, there is nothing printed to the screen (occurs with either version of `f` above):

```
>>> x = []
>>> g = f(x)
>>> for i in g:
...  pass
...
>>>
```

Can someone explain why does this output to the screen happens? I am thinking there is something interesting going on here but I don't know what it is.

To clarify, I surmise there is nothing complicated going on here than what happens when you do this:

```
>>> []
[]
```

The console is just repeating the result of an expression. But why is the console behaving as if there has been repeated expression entry in the case above?

Comment: Minimal example: `>>> while True: 0`

Comment: @JoshLee this explains everything. and luckily I knew better than to do it. :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#generator-iterator-methods):

> The send() method returns the next value yielded by the generator, or
> raises StopIteration if the generator exits without yielding another
> value.

Each time you call the `send()` method, it is returning the next value yielded by the generator.

In the interactive terminal, these returned results are printed to your screen. Nothing too magical.

Comment: makes sense. i guess i do not know why i found this surprising but i did.

Answer (score 0):

I feel dumb. The answer is so simple! This is an expression:

```
g.send(1)
```

...and just like any other expression, it will be printed to the console- multiple times if inside of a loop:

```
>>> 0
0
>>> for _ in range(2):
...  0
... 
0
0
```